# What difference does variable order/side make with relational operators?

Tags: php, syntax, operators

Compare:

```
if (donald_duck != null)
if (roast_potatoes > 9000)
if (love === 'explosions')
```

and

```
if (null != donald_duck)
if (9000 <= roast_potatoes)
if ('explosions' === love)
```

In the languages I've written in, I've always used the first order since it makes sense human-wise. e.g. "Is the parrot dead?" vs "Is dead what the parrot is?" However I've seen the (null == variable) order used a few times in various languages and places.

What operational difference does it make, and is one way more syntactically correct or widely adopted?

(I'm aware this may be different for various languages, so in particular I'm asking in regards to PHP)

Comment: Duplicate :S You can do both, it has a difference only in some [evaluation types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy)

Comment: [yoda condition it is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)

Comment: I tried searching SO with various phrases but couldn't find a question about it. Which question is this a duplicate of? I certainly wouldn't have searched for 'evaluation types' or 'yoda'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no different in the behavior but it helps to avoid errors for example in the comparisons.

if you use `obj == null` to compare, you have some risk of making a mistake and put`obj = null` instead causing problems in your code and having unexpected results.

But if you use `null == obj` to compare, that risk goes away because `null = obj` is not a valid sentence (you can't assign an object to `null`) and you will receive an error in compile time.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, it certainly did help! In a world of unit tests, inline evaluation and structured debugging, I think I'll avoid getting used to it. Cheers.